# How to configure Yarn to use all vcores?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We are running a spark streaming job using yarn as cluster manager, i have dedicated 7 cores per node to each node ...via yarn-site.xml as shown in the pic below

[image]

when the job is running ..it's only using **2 vcores** and **5 vcores** are left alone and the job is slow with lot of batches queued up ..

how can we make it use all the 7 vcores ..that's available to it this is usage when running so that it speed's up our job

[image]

Would greatly appreciate if any of the experts in the community will help out as we are new to Yarn & Spark

Comment: Could you give us the given parameters, such as executers-cores, executers-memory, executers-instances. This link helps you i think. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/running-on-yarn.html

Answer (score 3):

I searched many answers for this question. Finally, it worked after changing a yarn config file: `capacity-scheduler.xml`

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator</value>
</property>
```

Don't forget to restart your yarn

Comment: It is necessary perform tests, in some situations you need use the default configuration,

Check this for more details,
https://hortonworks.com/blog/managing-cpu-resources-in-your-hadoop-yarn-clusters/

I am still learning, I don't know what is better.

Answer (score 1):

At spark level you can control yarn application master's cores by using parameters `spark.yarn.am.cores`.

For spark executors you need to pass `--executor-cores` to `spark-submit`.

However from spark, you cannot control what(vcores/memory) yarn chooses to allocate to the container that it spawns which is right, as you are running spark over yarn.

In order to control that you will need to change yarn vcore parameters like `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores`, `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores`. More you can find here https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html#configuring_in_cm